Simple Bi-Weekly Data Input Sheet with Spin Button
I am trying to create an excel sheet to track my hours at work. I would like to have a simple sheet that will display 14 days where I can input my hours for those days. I am trying to have this data input change screens with the use of a spin button and automatically update data in a master sheet on another page. I am not sure how to have a small table be linked to a larger table like that and I don't know how to filter a table with a spin button. Can anyone help me?
Thank you so much :)
I have been able to create a dashboard showing two weeks of data from a master sheet but I have no Idea how to make a smaller sheet be the data input

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
